# Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound is raised even after rescuing

Tags: ruby, mongodb, error-handling, mongoid

I have a Rails controller with this method being triggered as a before_action:

```
  def authenticate_user
    Knock::AuthToken.new(token: token).entity_for(User)
  rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
    render nothing: true, status: 401
  end
```

Even though I can verify that it's rescuing the error(a byebug breakpoint gets triggered under the rescue statement), it still manages to be raised immediately after:

```
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound (
message:
  Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 1.
summary:
  When calling User.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 1 ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: 1.
resolution:
  Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.):

app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb:12:in `authenticate_user'
```

I've been using the rescue keyword for years in Ruby and have never encountered this.

What I'm running:

- Ruby 2.5
- Rails 5.2
- Mongoid 7.0.1

Why is it that the error gets raised even when I rescue it, and how can I prevent the error from getting raised?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa Sorry, I thought it was implicit but I'll clarify.  Why is it that the error seems to get raised even when I rescue it, and how can I prevent the error from getting raised?  I don't remember ever having an error "bubble" up like that when rescued.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it gets raised even when you rescue it, but I'll answer the "how to prevent it" part.

In your `mongoid.yml`, you need to set

```
raise_not_found_error: false
```

See [this section](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#mongoid-configuration-options) in the Mongoid docs for an example.

Comment: Got a 404 on the "this section" link.

Comment: @JulienLamarche Sorry about that, looks like the old link is dead. I updated it to a newer one.